# HTTP 500 error from domain name but not server name

Tags: java, http, servlets, websphere

I am getting HTTP 500 response when I try to access a URL. But when I replace the domain name with server name, it works fine. What can be causing the problem?

```
 java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://domainname/Test/test.jar
```

However, I am able to access other resources on the server like,
    http://domainname/Images/image.png

I have no idea whats going on.

Trace from the logs on WAS.

```
0000003d webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[dispatcher]: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: 
           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppDispatcherContext.sendError(WebAppDispatcherContext.java:637)
           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.sendError(SRTServletResponse.java:1180)
           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:131)
           at gov.pa.dot.entss.web.controller.BaseController.handleUncaughtException(BaseController.java:85)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver.doInvokeMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver.java:340)
           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver.java:132)
           at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:136)
           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:987)
           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:811)
           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1655)
           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1595)
           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
           at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
           at gov.pa.dot.entss.web.filter.ENTSSHttpFilter.doFilter(ENTSSHttpFilter.java:67)
           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:932)
           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:864)
           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
           at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
           at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
           at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
           at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
           at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
           at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
           at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
           at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1550)
```

Comment: When you are seeing this 500 error. Can you please post some log entries from $TOMCAT_HOME/log/catalina.out

Comment: This is running on WAS

Comment: See server log for exceptions and post it here.

Comment: Which OS you are using. Are you using Tivoli Integrated Portal (TIP)?

Comment: OS should be Windows 2008. I cannot answer about TIP. I am just a developer. Cannot answer admin and server related questions.

Comment: You need to find out the root cause of the exception, looks like you are consuming it and sending some generic exception without original info. Also check if your server is correctly configured with dns, e.g. use ping with domain name on your server with WAS. You can also add your domainname to the `/etc/hosts` file.

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved : Java cache on the WAS server has to be cleafed. Then restarting all clusters and nodes did the trick. Thanks for the help !!